# Search engines that do _not_ respect robots.txt?

Tags: search-engines, robots.txt

Are there any search engines that do not care about robots.txt?

Comment: Any reason you want to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the major, and minor, search engines respect robots.txt. Generally speaking only robots with bad intentions, or are poorly written, ignore robots.txt. You can find [a list of bad bots here](http://www.kloth.net/internet/badbots.php).

Comment: Thanks! The list is pretty old though, no entries later than 2007..

Comment: [There are others that seem to be more current you can check out.](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=bad+bots+list)